# How can i perform search operation on map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to mark some location on GoogleMap and then I want to perform search operation on that map.

I know how to mark place on map but the question is.

Is it possible to perform search operation on my on stored locations??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Have not developed API for google place search like google map. To do that same I performed action on search button. My application was related to property. So when user clicks on search Mumbai and clicks button I fetched all property lat and log from database and marked them on Mumbai and using camera method I just moved camera to Mumbai.